# Version problem on Azure Functions v1 (using .Net461/.Net472) with NotificationHub v3.1.0

Tags: azure, push-notification, version, azure-functions, conflict

I would like to run Azure Function v1 with .Net461/.Net472 for testing NotificationHub package. However, there is exception when executing below code:

```
await _hub.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registration);
```

Error is :

> Exception while executing function: PushRegister. Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried to downgrade to 10.0.3 then had error like

> Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0 ...

Below is the XXX.csproj file for reference:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\YYY\YYY.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: There is an assembly helper, you could have a try.https://github.com/nebosite/azure-functions-rocketscience/blob/ea717f597524b3035f09d0f8376904b183353806/src/AFRocketScienceShared/Tools/AssemblyHelper.cs#L20

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Nuget libraries have the dependency on `Newtonsoft` package, even the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` has a dependency on it but it is of older version.

**You cannot use any other Nuget Packages that have a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json version which is higher than the function runtime dependent version.**

When you try to install a NuGet which has the dependency on a higher version of Newtsonsoft package, you simply cannot install it. The only solution is to use an older version of that library that you need.

[image]

I have also written a blog on this and on github this is already an open issue

https://medium.com/@hharan618/common-issues-while-development-of-azure-functions-76b08299af58